# The type or namespace name "IJSRuntime" could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

In my Blazor serverside application, I am trying to inject JSRuntime according to this documentation: https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-javascript-from-dotnet/

To add JSRuntime to my project, I've added the following line in the ConfigureServices function of the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddSingleton<IJSRuntime, JSRuntime>();
```

At the top of my razor page, I have the following:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

When I try to compile, it gives an error at this injection with the message "The type or namespace name "IJSRuntime" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I've tried enabling "Use previews of the .NET SDK" as per stackoverflow suggestions, but it didn't help.

Comment: Add @using Microsoft.JSInterop to top of your razor page.  Or put this in the file labeled Imports.razor

Comment: Do you have `@using Microsoft.JSInterop` in either the razor page or in the _Imports.razor file? - lol what Jason said :)

Comment: Did you add reference to the Library in your project?

Comment: Ah, I had using Microsoft.JSInterop in my Startup class but not in the razor page. Thanks!

Comment: You should mark @Connor Low's answer as accepted.

Comment: One additional note. I don't think you should register IJSRuntime in your Composition Root. At least I don't the code `services.AddSingleton<IJSRuntime, JSRuntime>();` in any of my projects. 
Blazor University simply shows this interface as illustration and that's it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `using` statement, either in the component.razor file, or in *_Imports.razor* (preferred if you are going to be using `JSInterop` often):

```cs
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

If you the Server or WASM Blazor templates, this should already be included in *_Imports.razor*.